# The use of two separate GridControl in the form

Tags: c#, devexpress, gridcontrol

The form also has two separate GridControl, GridControl1 also has contact names phone numbers in GridControl2 there is a task and duration that each person has done. When I click on one of the GridControl1 that I want to do, the information about that person appears in GridCOntrol2.

also you can see below the c# DataGridView code:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            string filter = "";
            if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell != null)
                filter = $"KisiNo = {dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells["KisiNo"].Value}";
            (dataGridView2.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = filter;
        }
```

Comment: it is a datagridview :(

Comment: ur goal can only be achieved if details of each person is saved somewhre , like in a database or a list or a datatable

Comment: Dear Zack, Already saved in the information database I'm just looking gridview code how can I want to these code to the devexpress for in the use gridview.

Comment: give me a minute ...i'll post an answer

Comment: is it a datagridview or a devexpress gridview ?

Comment: I want to use it for GridView

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong : You have unique names in grid1 , when selected any -everything related to the name shows in grid2 ..the items shown in grid2 come from a database ... correct ?

Comment: both come from the database,  in the gridview1 has working times and There are people list at gridview2, when I click on the one person I just want that person's information to come to the gridview1.

Answer (score 0):

The GridControl object intended for displaying the detail data should be bound to an ADO.NET data relation(it will work if you have a correctly organized data-relations at the DataSet level):

```
gridControl1.DataSource = dataSet1.Contacts;
gridControl2.DataSource = dataSet1.Tasks;
gridControl2.DataMember = "ContactsTasks";
```

Take a look at the [How to Display Master-Detail Tables in Separate Grid Controls](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A378/how-to-display-master-detail-tables-in-separate-grid-controls) for details.

P.S. [The GridControl supports embedded master-detail data presentation out-of-the-box - take a look at the documentation to learn more](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/3473/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Master-Detail/Master-Detail-Relationships).